# RecyclerView in BottomSheet is not visible

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, bottom-sheet

I want to create a `bottomSheet`, where I have `recyclerView`. The problem is, that it doesn't show my `recyclerview`. Where the problem can be? This is my `bottomSheet` class.

```
public class MyBottomSheetDialogFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

public static final String TAG = "ActionBottomDialog";
private Context context;


public MyBottomSheetDialogFragment(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_wishlist_move_to, container, false);
    final RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_bottom_sheet_move_to);

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        list.add("Birthday " + i);
    }

    Adapter mAdapter = new Adapter(list);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    return view;
}


private class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.BottomSheetHolder> {

    private List<String> myList;

    private Adapter(List<String> list) {
        this.myList = list;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Adapter.BottomSheetHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        return new BottomSheetHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_wishlist_bottom_sheet, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Adapter.BottomSheetHolder holder, int position) {
        if (myList.size() == 0) return;

        holder.labelTitleCategory.setText(myList.get(position));
        holder.labelImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_icon);
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return myList.size();
    }


    private class BottomSheetHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        final TextView labelTitleCategory;
        final ImageView labelImage;

        public BottomSheetHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            labelTitleCategory = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            labelImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        }
    }
}
}
```

And here is the class, where I show the dialog.

```
button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            MyBottomSheetDialogFragment dialogWish = new MyBottomSheetDialogFragment(getContext());
            dialogWish.show(getFragmentManager(), WishListBottomSheetDialogFragment.TAG);
        });
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to add layout manger to recyclerview to show the item so do

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context);
```

By default, it will create vertical layout manger to show items vertically though can use [horizontal and grid, staggered mangers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager.html) etc

Comment: Oh thank you, I think the problem is there. I'm not in the office, I'll try tomorrow :)

Comment: @HaykMkrtchyan I am glad that I could help though please note the time stamp of answers (hover over time and see exact time) to find the first poster of the right answer. happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the layoutmanger for reyclerView

`LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager=new   LinearLayoutManager(context,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
        reyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager)`

Comment: Oh thank you, I think the problem is there. I'm not in the office, I'll try tomorrow, I'll accept this answer.